# Есть возможность передать параметры в файл.spec в %post скрипт во время установки rpm пакета?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, dnf

Пример: Для своих целей я вынужден собирать два rpm пакета идентичных на 98%.
Хотелось бы как то параметризовать установку, и пропихнуть %post скрипт(или еще куда) свой параметр. Ну или вообще как то по другому это решить. Что бы собирать один пакет.

Суть вопроса накидал в примере spec файла:

```
%install
install -D /opt/app/bin/* %{buildroot}/opt/app/bin

%post
[[ $1 == "test" ]] $$ echo "Ok" #как передать в $1 что-нибудь во время установки пакета


%files
%defattr (-,root,root)
/opt/app
```

Пакета будет ставится локально, например rpm -i app.rpm, yum/dnf install app.rpm, по любому из способов интересно послушать варианты, если они вообще есть.
Может можно что то типо такого провернуть:

```
rpm -i app.rpm --test
```

Вариант типо такого не подходит:

```
rpm -i app.rpm && echo "text" >> /opt/app/test_file.ini
```

Comment: Читать https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/ и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258647/rpm-install-time-parameters (именно в такой последовательности), чтобы разобраться в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Параметр `$1` в install/uninstall скриптах используется для передачи сведений о причинах запуска скрипта: `0` означает удаление пакета, `1` - установку, `2` - обновление (upgrade) уже установленного пакета. Другие параметры не поддерживаются. Этому есть свои причины. Если от вашего пакета будет зависеть другой пакет, как указать параметры для установки? В зависимостях можно записать только имя и ограничения по версии и архитектуре.

Поэтому я бы на вашем месте не старался оптимизировать сборку, и собирал бы два пакета.

Если же вы хотите минимизировать пересборку, то можно разделить пакет на три части:

1. Самая большая часть - общая. Назовём её `my-super-software-base`
2. Первый вариант установки: `my-super-software-test`, зависит от `my-super-software-base`. Скрипт этого пакета выполняет ту логику, которую вы хотели заложить в `if [ $1 == "test" ]; then ...`
3. Второй вариант установки: `my-super-software-release`, зависит от `my-super-software-base`. Соответственно, скрипт выполняет то, что вам нужно если `$1 != "test"`